# Create table on another schema

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Situation is that user1 gives permision to user2:

```
GRANT CREATE ANY TABLE, SELECT ANY TABLE TO user2;
```

And after logging on user2, I'm trying to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE user1.test(id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY);
```

the result is `ORA-01031 - insufficient privileges`
I can create table on own schema and select tables from other schemas. I thought that `CREATE ANY TABLE` solves the problem, but it looks other way. Ah, and both users have unlimited tablespace. What else should I guarantee?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you need to also grant `CREATE ANY INDEX`? You are creating an index when you add the primary key. You can quickly test this by omitting the PK constraint.

Answer (score 4):

"create any table" is too powerful a privilege to be granting to non-DBA's. A better approach would be to create a "create table" procedure in the target schema that accepts sanitised components of the required DDL, and grant execute privilege on that to the required users.

A suitable interface would be something like ...

```
create procedure
  create_table(
    table_name varchar2,
    columns    varchar2,
    etc        varchar2)
```

... so that you can ...

```
begin
  user1.create_table(
    table_name => 'TEST',
    columns    => 'id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY',
    etc        => '');
end;
```

... and have the procedure construct and execute the DDL for you.

Answer (score -2):

user 
GRANT CREATE ANY INDEX TO SCHEMA_NAME